# Is there a difference between deglazing and honing a cylinder?

Tags: automotive-engineering, machining

I have not been able to figure out if deglazing means exactly the same as honing (when talking specifically about honing/deglazing a cylinder), or if there is some difference between the two?

I will share my thoughts/findings below.

- Some sources appear to use the two interchangably.
- English is not my native language, but apparently the word *deglazing* is mostly known from deglazing a frying pan. A process in which residue stuck to the pan is removed. So I wondered if deglazing on a cylinder refers to removing some kind of gunk/residue in the grooves, rather than creating new grooves?
- The wikipedia article on [deglazing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deglazing_(cooking)) does not mention honing, and the wikipedia article on [honing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honing_(metalworking)) does not mention deglazing.

Comment: Deglazing has to do with removing a likeness to glass (an objective) so either a shiney coating or a shiney finish.  Honing has to do with how - scrubbing with abrasive (as opposed to an operation that produces chips) of which common objectives include getting a specific finish or very finely toleranced geometry.

Comment: Du Mads, er du Dansk?

Comment: Hvad hvis jeg er? :)

Comment: @MadsSkjern oh I don't know, perhaps from Mars? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

These are two different things.

Deglazing is done to remove the "burnt or cooked" oil coating from the cylinder walls during an overhaul if the cylinders are in good enough condition to not need a rebore. This is so thaat the rings will seat properly.

Honing is a process to finish the surface after a rebore or to remove light scoring or scuffing on the cylinder walls that does not warrant a rebore.

Note, a rebore will need oversize pistons which add to the cost so if a rebore can be avoided then it helps with the cost. Of course, making the correct choice is crucial as doing it twice is worse...

Answer (score 0):

To add to Solar Mike's answer, a *cylinder hone* is designed to produce a certain scratch pattern or texture to the cylinder bore walls which then causes the piston rings and the bore itself to "wear in" quickly and yield a very close fit after a few hundred miles of driving.